# Getting "Argument not optional" error on segment of code

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting "Argument not optional" on this Sub. The `.Add` word always gets highlighted as well.

I've tried using `Set` and declaring the collection in the Sub and in the calling function. Setting the argument as `ByRef` nor `Optional` works either.

```
Sub getDescriptions(ByRef descriptions As Collection)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Set descriptions = New Collection
    Do While Cells(i + 3, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(i + 3, 2).Value <> ""
        descriptions.Add = Cells(i + 3, 2).Value & " - Test Period " & Cells(i + 3, 4).Value & " - " & Cells(i + 3, 5).Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Public descriptions as Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    'calling Sub
    With Application.ActiveWindow
        Me.Left = .Left + (.Width - Me.Width) / 2
        Me.Top = .Top + (.Height - Me.Height) / 2
    End With
    Set descriptions = New Collection
    getDescriptions (descriptions)
...
```

Comment: I think it would help to know how you are calling the sub as well... and given that you are supposed to pass the description as an argument, why set it as new?

Comment: Are you passing the collection as an argument?

Comment: I've added my calling Sub

Answer (score 3):

There's the problem:

```
descriptions.Add = {expression}
```

You're invoking the `Add` method without any parameters, and then attempting to assign *to its return value* (and I don't think it has one).

Syntactically, that's as follows:

- Take the `descriptions` collection
- Invoke its `Add` method without any arguments (compile error: argument not optional)
- Take the return value (there isn't one, but that's syntactically irrelevant) and, assuming it's an object with a default property, assign that to the expresion on the right-hand side of the `=` operator.

If the `Add` method didn't require any arguments and returned an object reference, your code could be valid. Since it *does* have a non-optional parameter, and doesn't return anything, it's a compile error.

Remove the `=` operator, you'll get this:

```
descriptions.Add {expression}
```

Which is as follows:

- Take the `description` collection
- Invoke its `Add` method, pass `{expression}` as an argument

---

This is also a problem:

```
getDescriptions (descriptions)
```

Remove the parentheses; they are forcing the object reference to be evaluated as a value expression - and the `Collection` class' default property (invoked when let-coercing the object during expression evaluation) being its parameterized `Item(Index)` member, you can't legally do that. Note that if the default property wasn't parameterized, you would be passing its value `ByVal`, regardless of `getDescriptions` specifying `ByRef`.

That said the `descriptions` parameter only needs to be passed `ByRef` because you are reassigning *the object reference itself* with that `Set` statement - a rather bug-prone thing to do with a global variable.

Comment: One other issue - if this code is all located in the same module, `Public descriptions as Collection` should be in the declarations section. Would be caught when using `Option Explicit`. But I am confused why OP is passing public vars as an argument anyway.